# How to convert a List[java.lang.Long] to a List[scala.Long]

Tags: java, scala, type-conversion

I'm trying to convert from a java List to a scala List[scala.Long], i have seen from scala to java, but not the other way around.

I have tried using:

```
def convertJavaList2ScalaList[A]( list : java.util.List[A] ) : List[A] 
     ={
         val buffer = list.asScala
         buffer.toList
     }
```

And it works for other Objects (Eg. Person), but doesn't work when i try to convert scala.Long to java.lang.Long

Thanks for the help.

Comment: `.asScala` is not (fortunately) supposed to convert the component/item type, have to `.map`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

// given a Java List of Java Longs:
val jlist: java.util.List[java.lang.Long] = ???

val scalaList: List[Long] = jlist.asScala.toList.map(_.toLong)
```